# Touch bar not functioning properly

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-bar

I have 13inch Macbook pro with touch bar late 2018 model. Having macOS Catalina 10.15.2 .
Recently I started facing issues with touch bar. Now it is happening quite often. It starts working on its own without even touching it. I continuously keeps on pressing ESC key without even touching it. When sometimes I try to slide though volume key it doesn't respond to my touch rather keeps on increasing decreasing volume on its own. Its like functions on touch bar often works on their own.

Comment: Boot into Safe Mode and Recovery Mode.  Do the symptoms persist?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.

Comment: Try resetting your [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and your [SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT201295)